# Ubuntu Powerbook G4 video card driver help

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

So I am looking at my sysinfo, and my video card, which is a Mobility Radeon 9600 M10, says

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
```

That means a driver is missing right?

But above there, it says

```
configuration: driver=agpgart-uninorth latency=16
```

So if that is the driver installed, is there any way I can change that to the driver that I already have installed, I think its called radeon.4.gz. It shows up when I type

```
man radeon
```

And that config file shows my video card as being supported, but I don't think my video card is using it.

Any help would be grand!

Here is the code.

```
    lspci -k | grep VGA -A2 0000:00:10.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced
    Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] Subsystem:     
    Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10]    
    Kernel modules: radeonfb
```

Comment: Some help would be great.

Comment: Please [edit] your question ans add output of "lspci -k | grep VGA -A2" terminal command there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information there. It looks OK. Are there any problems?

Comment: Ok, it is changed. The problem is that the driver configuration seems to be using a radeonfb driver, when I think it should be using the radeon.4.gz driver. Is that correct? At least I think the radeon driver would be better suited for the laptop.

Comment: The driver is correct. It could not be "gz" there.

Comment: So which line if text is the driver?  The agpart-uninorth or the radeonfb part?

Comment: radeonfb is the driver. It is kernel driver module.

Answer (score 0):

This does not mean that video driver is missing. Otherwise you would not be able to use your system in GUI mode. If you run

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

you will see more details on your graphics adapter. But it won't improve anything in your system